Как избежать отметки рассылки как спама?
Написал скрипт на питоне, использующий протокол SMTP. При запуске  отправляется сообщение пользователю из словаря.
Планируется отправлять до 250 писем в неделю (до 50 в день) с действующей рабочей почты.
Однако, есть опасения, что используемый рабочий домен будет отмечен почтовым сервером как аккаунт для спама.
Вопрос: как этого избежать? Возможно, не стоит опасаться вовсе, с учётом механики скрипта и количества отправляемых сообщений?
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from datetime import time, datetime

emails = {} #тут будет словарь в котором ключ - почта, значение - имя

for key, value in emails.items():
    def send_ya_mail(key: str, message: str):
        login = ''
        password = 'тут пароль от почтового клиента'

        msg = MIMEText(f'{value}, {message}', 'plain', 'utf-8')
        msg['From'] = login
        msg['To'] = key

        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru', 587, timeout=10)

        try:
            s.starttls()
            s.login(login, password)
            s.sendmail(msg['From'], key, msg.as_string())
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    def main():
            send_ya_mail(key, message='Добрый день, планируются ли в ближайшее время заявки на закупку?')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Письма транзакционные? Список получателей всегда меняется?

Очень часто почтовые рассылки попадают в спам если:

Отрицательная репутация почтового домена
Получатели ранее отмечали ваши сообщения как спам
Резкое увеличение получателей
Различные вложения файлов, фотографий без текста, недопустимые слова и
т.д

